# Double Summation Simplification (Simple)

Tags: summation

[image]

My questions:

1. For the inner summation, When $j=i$ does that mean $j$ will equal $2$ because $i$ equals $2$?
2. I'm confused and stuck on the yellow, because I thought it would just be $n$.  NOT ($(n-i+n)$. I understandstand Line 1 of the problem somewhat. It's just the index of the inner j=i is throwing me off.

Comment: Could you type out specifically what you're talking about in the question? It's a little harder to parse flipping tabs.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=a}^{b}\sum_{j=i}^{b} f(i) = \left(\sum_{j=a}^b f(j)\right)+\left(\sum_{j=a+1}^b f(j)\right)+\ldots+\left(\sum_{j=b-1}^b f(j)\right)+\left(\sum_{j=b}^b f(j)\right)$$
 
Double sum is just a shorthand notation to express this. The rule here is to work from inner sums towards the outer sums, while keeping the outer sum variables constant. Although, there are a few cases when this doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $2 \leq i \leq n$, we have 
$$
\sum_{j=i}^{n}3i = \underset{(n-i+1\ \text{times})}{3i + \cdots + 3i} = (n-i+1)3i.
$$

For each $i \geq 1$
the number of the elements of the set $\{ i, i+1, \dots, n \}$ is simply $n-i+1$, as you can try to prove; for instance, if $i=2$ and if $n = 4$, then the set $\{ i, i+1, \dots, n\} = \{ 2, 3, 4 \}$ has $3 = n-i+1$ elements.

Comment: (n-i )will give me the total amount of cycles that inner summation with look through.. why is there a +1?

Comment: You’re making the classic “fencepost error.” If $j$ ranges from $i$ to $n$ _inclusive_ it will take on $n-j+1$ values, not $n-j$. Try $n=1$ and $j=0$, for example.

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of summation notation $ \Sigma $ follows as:
$$ \sum^{n}_{k=i}(\text{formula of }k) = \text{Let's sum a formula of }k\text{  when }k=i, i+1, i+2 \ldots n.$$

so for your question 1, j=i does not mean j=2, even if it is placed right after i=2.

Actually,
$$ \sum^{n}_{k=i}(\text{formula of }k)$$
can be written equivalently as(but don't use this notation if your lecture giver insists)
$$ \sum_{k \in \{i, i+1, i+2, ... n\}}(\text{formula of }k)$$
so an equal sign does not have the meaning you think.

So, for your question 2, 
$$ \sum^{n}_{j=i}1 = \sum_{j \in \{i, i+1, i+2 ... n\}} 1 \\
= \text{sum of }(n - i + 1) \text{ } 1\text{'s} \\
= n - i + 1.$$

Hope my answer helps.